# How to see errors suppressed by '@'?

Tags: php, error-handling

I joined this crazy company as a Site Administrator. Now I did some changes to my db configurations which have impacted the PHP scripts execution.

Strange part is PHP scripts just die. They don't throw any errors. When I went inside the scripts I realized they have used @ error suppression directive. Now the whole codebase is million of lines spread over thousands of file and don't want to run something like sed to replace '@'.

But '@' has made debugging impossible for me. Its like developers are closing their eyes and find vision dark are saying its night.

Is there a way I can undo error suppression done by '@' and let php log directive handle it. Touching the codebase is not an option. I am looking forward for a way where I can do this by modifying the php configuration or adding few lines in the bootstrap file.

Comment: what's wrong with search and replace? certainly easier than patching the PHP engine.

Comment: Just replacing '@' with '' would replace it also at the places it isn't used for suppression. Say a file containing emails id or regex code verifying that.

Comment: in short, don't replace it in strings and comments. doable in.. let's overestimate.. an hour?

Comment: You can't make PHP ignore the error suppression operator. You *must* remove it, and then optionally go beat your programmers with a sack of doorknobs for using it in the first place. `find /path/to/approot -name '*.php' -exec grep -H '@' {} \;` and then have fun.

Comment: You should be able to use `set_error_handler()` and log the error through `if (0 === error_reporting()) { ... }`. See Elad Yosifon's answer on the manual page for an example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Normally `@` that supresses errors would stay only at the beginning of the line, so I do not see a problem removing all `@`s with `sed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org) installed and enabled (in development, you should) then you can set the [xdebug.scream](http://xdebug.org/docs/basic#scream) configuration option, which disables the @-operator.

Alternatively, the [scream PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.scream.php) also disables the @-operator (and that's all it does).

Basically you install the extension then set the `scream.enabled` ini setting to true/on.

Answer (score 6):

Muted errors are still visible for the handler installed via `set_error_handler`. So you can just add something like this to your bootstrap file:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo "$errstr at $errfile($errline)\n";
});
```

or, better,

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 1, $errfile, $errline);
});
```

which also would display the stack.